# Convert string ISO 8601 Date Time standard to SQL DateTime using powershell?

Tags: powershell, datetime

$string ='2015-10-14T14:43:55-04:00'

Expected result

$string ='2015-10-14 14:43:55'

In SQL the field is Nvarchar

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
$string ='2015-10-14T14:43:55-04:00'
Get-Date -Date $string -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

2015-10-14 14:43:55